# Stash intervals with consequent same value in PostgrerSQL

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table:

| Status | Date |
| --- | --- |
| ok | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 |
| ok | 2023-05-01 00:01:00 |
| ok | 2023-05-01 00:02:00 |
| no | 2023-05-01 00:03:00 |
| no | 2023-05-01 00:04:00 |
| ok | 2023-05-01 00:04:00 |
| ok | 2023-05-01 00:05:00 |

I want to stash statuses coming having the same value and coming in a row and save status, start, end. So the above table would be transformed into:

| Status | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ok | 2023-05-01 00:00:00 | 2023-05-01 00:02:00 |
| no | 2023-05-01 00:03:00 | 2023-05-01 00:04:00 |
| ok | 2023-05-01 00:04:00 | 2023-05-01 00:05:00 |

How can I do this using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of dealing with this problem is:

- generating a flag that recognizes when the status has changed
- computing a running sum on the flag, to get the new partitions
- aggregating on minimum and maximum dates within the partitions

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           CASE WHEN LAG("Date") OVER(PARTITION BY "Status" ORDER BY "Date") = "Date" - INTERVAL '1 minute' 
                THEN 0 ELSE 1 
           END AS "changed_part" 
    FROM tab
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, 
           SUM("changed_part") OVER(PARTITION BY "Status" ORDER BY "Date") AS "parts"
    FROM cte 
)
SELECT "Status",
       MIN("Date") AS "Start",
       MAX("Date")   AS "End"
FROM cte2 
GROUP BY "Status", "parts"
ORDER BY "Start"
```

**Output**:

| Status | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ok | 2023-05-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2023-05-01T00:02:00.000Z |
| no | 2023-05-01T00:03:00.000Z | 2023-05-01T00:04:00.000Z |
| ok | 2023-05-01T00:04:00.000Z | 2023-05-01T00:05:00.000Z |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mHcphNEkBy6nQYKgFnDg2d/2).

Note: This solution works under the assumption that the time distance between consecutive status detection is fixed, as per sample data, to a specific time distance.

Comment: I like this approach quite a bit. I think the only drawback is that it's relies on the statuses being exactly 1 minute apart, so if there is any irregularity in the data you may get results different from what is desired.

Comment: Neither that is the problem, as it would be tweakable by substituting `=` with `>=` in the first cte. The real limitation is if the distance between consecutive status detections is not fixed. I guess this is a kind of compromise between efficiency and effectiveness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
--afterwards select the earliest start time for that end time
select min( start_time), mstatus, end_time
from (
   --inside get the latest end times for each start time; this will have duplicates that only vary depending on start time
   select s.mdate as start_time, s.mstatus 
   , max(f.mdate) as end_time

   from statuses s
   join statuses f on f.mstatus = s.mstatus
    and s.mdate < f.mdate
    and not exists (select 1 from statuses m where m.mstatus <> s.mstatus and m.mdate > s.mdate and m.mdate < f.mdate)
   group by s.mdate, s.mstatus ) t
group by t.mstatus, t.end_time
```

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o5v9CtBaQZuXsC4XaSB1Cv/0